# How to get list of pixel coordinates[x, y] of certain color(RGB) with python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I'm trying to make an indoor navigation and I need indoor map that robot can automatically navigate the way.
I'm thinking of using image which have different colors for each place(certain section), and I want to know the way to get the coordinates of the certain colors. So that I can designate places to certain color area using that coordinate. How can I get the list of pixel coordinates of the image which have certain color using python? In this case, I know RGB code of color! I am currently using pycharm

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your picture has shape (Y, X, 3). `Y` is the height of the image and `X` the width. Last dimension is for the 3 RGB colors channels.

You can use this code on the image to get a list of pixels coordinates with particular RGB set:

```
def pixels(image, rgb_set):
  set = list()

  for j in range(0, image.shape[0]):
    for i in range(0, image.shape[1]):
      if image[j][i] == rgb_set:
        set.append([j, i])

  return set
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I don't know how to adapt this in my case. Can your check this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63723257/how-can-i-get-pixel-coordinates-of-certain-colorrgb-of-this-image-using-python

Comment: for exemple to get the list of the pink pixels you have to use my function like this : `pinks = pixels(image, [255, 128, 255])`

Comment: After that `pinks` will contains a list of [x, y] coordinates for each pink pixels of the image

Comment: import cv2


def pixels(image, rgb_set):
    set = list()

    for j in range(0, image.shape[0]):
        for i in range(0, image.shape[1]):
            if image[j][i] == rgb_set:
                set.append([j, i])
    return set


image = cv2.imread("map_eng.jpg")
pinks = pixels(image, [255, 128, 255])
print(pinks)

Comment: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()           --> I get this error..do you know why?Thank you so much for your help

Comment: can you please edit your answer width the result of the command : `print(your_image.shape)` and `print(your_image[0][0].shape)`. It'll give me some informations to help you