# How can I get pixel coordinates of certain color(RGB) of this image using python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, pycharm

I'm trying to make an indoor navigation and I need indoor map that robot can automatically navigate the way. I'm thinking of using image which have different colors for each place(certain section), and I want to know the way to get the coordinates of the certain colors. So that I can designate places to certain color area using that coordinates. I am currently using pycharm

How can I get the coordinates of each of the pink,purple, and yellow part?
RGB code of the colors are pink(255,128,255), yellow(255,255,0), purple(128,128, 255).

[This is the image that I'll use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCoKb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem will involve two main parts:

1. Detecting the color from input image
2. Converting the blob to a single coordinate.

Let's take the first problem. You can use `cv2.inRange()` with various colors, to get a binary mask for each of your marked squares in the input image.

Now you can use `cv2.findContours` on the binary mask(s) to detect the largest contour and the take it's mid-point or something.